# Additional Processing to turn Invalid Text Formatted 'almost' Dates into Valid Dates

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have several files each with roughly 74k records.  In some of these Text/Varchar columns is a mix of actual valid dates and invalid dates and so when importing it is failing on records with these invalid dates.  When looking at these I can intuitively convert most of these to a valid date.

**How can I perform a second date check on fields that originally fail due to these dates?  I want to expand and add a secondary check against what I'm calling** *almost* **dates.**

In the code below in the loop `# Scan fields for dates.`
My code below has an if statement inside of a foreach loop where I am checking for invalid dates.  It is here I am needing to perform an additional check and return a valid date if possible.

```
# Declare File Paths
$SourceFile = "AlmostDates.tsv"
$ExportFile = "AlmostDates_Updated.tsv"

# Import Data
$ProcessData  = Import-Csv $SourceFile -Delimiter "`t"
$countValidDates = 0

$totalrecords = (import-csv $sourcefile).count

Write-Host $totalRecords

$ProcessData |
ForEach-Object {
    
    # Loop Thru ALL field values and if NOT Null preform a replace to remove TABs and Double Quotes from within each field
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
    {
        if ( ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($property.Value)  ) {
            # Replace Double Quotes, Tabs, Carriage Returns and New Lines within Fields and Trim.  Note: TABs are replaced with a space.
            $property.Value = $property.Value -replace '\"','' -replace "`t",' ' -replace "`r",'' -replace "`n",''
            $property.Value = $property.Value.Trim()
            
            # Scan fields for dates.  
            if ( ( $property.Value -as [datetime] )  ) {
                #Write-Host "$($property.Value) is a date"
                $countValidDates++
                $property.Value = (Get-Date $property.Value).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')                
            } else {
                
                # Perform additional Date Checks on invalid dates to see if they could be turned into actual dates
                Write-Host $property.Value
                
                # If the field absolutely cannot be converted set it to NULL so import does not fail.
                $property.Value = $null
            }
        }
    }  
    # Output the updated object
    $_
} | 
Export-Csv $ExportFile -Delimiter "`t" -UseQuotes Never -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "The number of valid Dates Found: $countValidDates"
```

## 17 Distinct Invalid Dates in the file AlmostDates.tsv

```
InvalidDates
05_11_2022
10142020
10132022
NULL
6/15/2020 6/16/2020
7/
09012022
02262021
05042021
ES
01252021
01262021
01202021
03/202022
10202022
Last week
10/06//2022
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following :

```
$filename = 'c:\temp\test.txt'
$formats = [string[]]@('MM_dd_yyyy', 'MMddyyyy','M/d/yyyy')
$lines = Get-Content -Path $filename
foreach($line in $lines)
{
   $splitArray = $line.split([string[]]@("`t", " "))
   foreach($date in $splitArray)
   {
      $dt = New-Object DateTime
      $isDate = [DateTime]::TryParseExact($date, $formats, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref] $dt)
      if($isDate -eq $true)
      {
         Write-Host "$date is valid"
      }
      else
      {
         Write-Host "$date is not valid"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I've seen several examples of `[DateTime]::TryParseExact` but this answer is the first time I am seeing you can use a string array for the formats.  Showing me how to test against several different date formats in one go is exactly what I was needing and it is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The following tries to parse the invalid tokens as US-format dates (month-first; in the case of `6/15/2020 6/16/2020`, the *last* date is used), if possible, recognizes `Last Week` as referring to the start of today's calendar date 1 week ago, and reporting a warning for any tokens that cannot be parsed:

```bash
@(
  '05_11_2022'
  '10142020'
  '10132022'
  'NULL'
  '6/15/2020 6/16/2020'
  '7/'
  '09012022'
  '02262021'
  '05042021'
  'ES'
  '01252021'
  '01262021'
  '01202021'
  '03/202022'
  '10202022'
  'Last week'
  '10/06//2022'
) | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $dt = ($_ -replace '\D' -replace '(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})', '$1-$2-$3') -as [datetime]
    if ($dt) {
      $dt
    }
    elseif ($_ -eq 'Last week') {
      (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-7)
    }
    elseif ($dt = (-split $_)[-1] -as [datetime]) {
      $dt
    }
    else {
      Write-Warning "Unrecognized timestamp: $_"
    }
  }
```

Comment: So easy to follow.  You taught me how to create a simple dates array and loop thru it.  I've been importing my file of dates as I didn't think to look up how to make something simpler.  I incorporated in my testing.  I ended up choosing jdweng's answer as the most correct answer.  It was his use of the $formats array that got the win however I used your syntax/structure to test it out.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @CodeNovice. Yes, using multiple formats with `[datetime]::TryParseExact()` is more robust and maintainable than my regex-based approach.